# Setting Regional format with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, intune

I'm trying to set some Regional Settings for all devices in my company. So far I didn't have any problems with Keyboard Layouts etc. but I can't find a way to control the highlighted settings with PowerShell..
Does anyone know how to control these settings with PowerShell?

[image]

I've already tried the Set-WinSystemLocal CMDlet but I cannot find a way to check the highlighted settings.

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:powershell-2.0]? Any operating systems that would've shipped with 2.0 is at least 3 years out of support at this point

Comment: Those checkboxes aren’t *settings* - they’re *actions* that get taken when you click “ok”. They copy the settings in the “current user” part of the dialog into the “welcome screen” and “new user accounts” parts of the dialog. You can confirm this by checking the boxes, clicking “ok” and then re-opening the dialog - the boxes will be unchecked by default. Your question is really “how do I set the ‘welcome screen’ and ‘new user account’ settings?”

Comment: @mclayton thank you for the reply. You are absolutely right about the actions. I want to set the 'Welcome Screen' and 'new user account' settings with Powershell. 
I stumbled accross the cmdlet Copy-UserInternationalSettingsToSystem with the handles -WelcomeScreen $True -NewUser $True however running these commands does not change the settings. The regional format etc for the Welcome Screen and New Users is still the same. If i check the boxes by hand it works fine. 
Any Help is appreciated.

Comment: @trigger_bison, my guess is that the settings are stored in the registry, such as at `HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT` for new user accounts. You could try to use [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to monitor the registry changes while you perform the changes interactively, and infer what you need to programmatically from there.